# How to resolve Liquibase changeSet error?

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, liquibase

I have use Liquibase for my spring hibernate web application.  Now I added new change set to update my database.  When I try to restart my web application, Liquibase  asks  to drop database. But in my case I want to update my db schema without drop existing schema. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Lakshmi Priya.K

Answer (score 0):

There is a "dropFirst" property on the spring implementation of liquibase:

- http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/spring.html

This might be your issue.

Are you sure liquibase is dropping the schema and not just the [objects within the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300998/liquibasedropall-didnt-delete-schema/18302547#18302547)?

## Update

I found more details about the "dropFirst" property (see [CORE-964](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-964)). It is indeed performing a *dropAll* liquibase action.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding unused Autowire in the Controllers and specifying the

Liquibase Query in the root-context.xml without any space will solve the issue...

Liquibase works fine without database drop..

Thanks

Lakshmi Priya.K